# How To Use Relational Operators In Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using visual Studio 2012 and I am making a sample of a mobile shop. I have a feature of Buying a Mobile from my customer. What I want to do is if the user is selling a mobile above $1000 then I will display a message that we don't want it.

```
    if(tb3->Text >=1000)
    MessageBox::Show("Sorry We Dont Buy It");
```

`tb3` is the name of the text box I will store the price of mobile.

Now compiler shows an error:

> error C2676 : Binary '>=' : System ::String Does not define this operator

Can any one tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: what is `tb3->Text` ? Please read about [mcve]

Comment: Convert `tb3->Text` to a number before comparing.

Comment: ...and please include the exact error message in the question

Comment: tb3 is name of textbox in which i will store price of mobile

Comment: And Error Message Says :
error C2676 : Binary '>=' : System ::String Does not define this operator

Comment: isnt the error quite clear? You cannot compare a string to an int, well... unless you define what that is supposed to mean, or more easily convert the string to an int

Answer (score 1):

The following code will get the c string pointer and parse it to an int:

```
if(atoi(tb3->Text.c_str()) >=1000)
    MessageBox::Show("Sorry We Dont Buy It");
```